# Get 3 rows data in 1 row

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

My records looks like:

```
aid  cmpyname  rid  imgpath

 1      abc     1   ~/img/aa.jpg:~/img/bb.jpg:~/img/cc.jpg:
 2      abc     1   ~/img/dd.jpg:~/img/ee.jpg:~/img/ff.jpg:

 3      xyz     2   ~/img/gg.jpg:~/img/hh.jpg:~/img/ii.jpg:
 4      xyz     2   ~/img/jj.jpg:~/img/kk.jpg:~/img/ll.jpg:
```

What I want to get is displayed below - but in a single query

```
cmpyname  rid  imgpath

  abc     1   ~/img/aa.jpg:~/img/bb.jpg:~/img/cc.jpg:~/img/dd.jpg:~/img/ee.jpg:~/img/ff.jpg:

  xyz     2   ~/img/gg.jpg:~/img/hh.jpg:~/img/ii.jpg:~/img/jj.jpg:~/img/kk.jpg:~/img/ll.jpg:
```

How can I do so? I haven't provided any relationship so please keep it in mind.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct rid,imgpath,rid from(
select imgpath=(select imgpath + ', ' AS 'data()' 
FROM tbl_Temp 
where tbl_Temp.rid=rid   FOR XML PATH('')  ) 
,id,cmpyname,rid from tbl_Temp
) as temp
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...!!
I also got it done with my way - My Query

select rpid, cmpyname, stuff((select ':' + allimgs from tbladimages AS A where (rpid = B.rpid) for XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS allimgs from tbladimages AS B group by rpid, cmpyname

Comment: @NelsonPrajapati, Be aware of the commas (you did not add commas in your example...) and especially the last comma which was not taken away (you could use STUFF or LEFT)

Comment: Yes @Shnugo
Any ways thanks for the solutions Guys...!!
Really appreciated...!!

Answer (score 3):

```
select max(cmpyname) as cmpyname, rid,
stuff((
    select imgpath
    from Records t1
    where t1.rid = t2.rid
    order by t1.aid
    for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 0, ''
) as imgpath
from Records t2
group by rid;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/46822/1

Comment: Hi @daniel, just one hint: You don't need STUFF if there is nothing to replace or cut away, you don't even need the ",TYPE" with the ".value(). If you look at my answer, which is roughly the same, you'll find, that you can get the same with less effort

Comment: stuff here used to cut away the begin <imgpath> and end </imgpath> in the xml

Comment: No, have a look at your STUFF-parameters. You state, that there is a string (your sub-select) and STUFF should look on position 1 and replace 0 characters with an empty string. Have a look at the STUFF syntax...

Comment: OK, both of us made a mistake... My example was missing the "add a blank to imgpath" to get rid of the implicit column name. Try your fiddle with `select '' + imgpath`. The STUFF function has a completely different meaning...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

Just paste into into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(aid INT,  cmpyname VARCHAR(100),  rid INT,  imgpath VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'abc',1,'~/img/aa.jpg:~/img/bb.jpg:~/img/cc.jpg:')
,(2,'abc',1,'~/img/dd.jpg:~/img/ee.jpg:~/img/ff.jpg:')
,(3,'xyz',2,'~/img/gg.jpg:~/img/hh.jpg:~/img/ii.jpg:')
,(4,'xyz',2,'~/img/jj.jpg:~/img/kk.jpg:~/img/ll.jpg:');

SELECT DISTINCT tbl.cmpyname
      ,tbl.rid
      ,(
            SELECT '' + x.imgpath
            FROM @tbl AS x
            WHERE x.rid=tbl.rid
            FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS allPaths
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.cmpyname, B.rid,
(
    SELECT imgpath + '' FROM tbl1 AS A WHERE (B.rid = A.rid) FOR XML PATH('')
) AS imgpath

FROM tbl1 AS B
```